# Retrieve how many types are in a column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a db with this data

```
"id" , "desc"                        , "tipo"
"37" , "Acai Tropitalia Surgelato"   , "Frutta"
"38" , "Acerola Tropitalia Surgelata", "Frutta"
"1"  , "Aceto Balsamico"             , "Liquido"
"187", "Aceto di Mele BIO"           , "Liquido"
"2"  , "Acido Citrico"               , "Solido"
"3"  , "Acqua"                       , "Liquido"
"39" , "Albicocca Fresca"            , "Frutta"
```

and i would like to know how many "tipo" are in the table, for examples the query in this table return

```
"tipo"
"Frutta"
"Liquido"
"Solido"
```

how can create the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `distinct` keyword to return a distict list of `tipo` column values:

```
select distinct tipo from mytable
```